# Почему не работает WebShare API?

Tags: api

Проблема такая - решил реализовать на сайте кнопку "Поделиться", на сайте [Medium](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-webshare-api-bd1aa458115d)
даётся первый пример с пройстейшей реализацией WebShare API, но что странно - кнопка не работает, и выдаёт ошибку при нажатии - "Sorry! Your browser does not support Web Share API". Протестировал на трёх десктопных браузерах: Firefox, Chrome и Midori - ни один не поддерживает. Решил через [GitHub](https://github.com/IcEWaRRiOr01/testing-share-api/) залить сайт на [Versel](https://testing-share-api.vercel.app/) - на сайте выдаёт ту же ошибку, а при попытке зайти на по ссылке на Vercel cо смартфона - браузер выдаёт ошибку "Этот сайт не может обеспечить безопасное соединение Сайт testing-share-api.versel.app отправил недействительный ответ.", хотя на другой свой сайт на Versel я спокойно захожу... Кэш и куки чистил.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Если у вас линукс, то в нём Web Share API и не работает

Comment: А на моём телефоне всё работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DheW.jpg

Comment: @andreymal ну да, линукс... А почему на нём не работает Web Share API, и есть ли способ, чтобы на линуксе это работало?

Comment: @andreymal а какой у вас браузер, просто на моём Samsung Internet Browser-е выдаёт вышеописанную ошибку. Даже через прокси пробовал

Comment: На линуксе в принципе отсутствует штатная фича "Поделиться", так что и Web Share API на нём тоже взять неоткуда

Comment: Зачем использовать какой-то непонятный Samsung Internet Browser, когда можно поставить нормальный Chrome?

Comment: @andreymal так этот браузер как раз и сделан на базе Хрома, а конкретней - Chromium. Видимо, надо будет скачать обычный Хром...

Comment: На базе какой-нибудь очень-очень старой версии Хрома скорее всего. Особенно если у вас телефон сам по себе старый...

Comment: Нет, браузер обновлён до последней версии, и телефон новый - Samsung Galaxy A21s

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121179/discussion-between-icewarrior-and-andreymal).